# Microsoft Graph Explorer / Microsoft Teams - 404 respond

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

when I'm trying to test *ms teams* api it always returns 404
For example - the simplest query: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource not found.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-07-24T08:47:53",
            "request-id": "0ae3aa34-4aa5-4609-ac6b-01c2aba09b24"
        }
    }
}
```

I made test team, added couple of test users etc.

Comment: did you login first? how do you send the request? I'm getting InvalidAuthenticationToken when I use your link...

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm using Microsoft Graph Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Are you part of any team?

Comment: Yes, I made couple of just to be sure.

Comment: is it giving this error -inside- graph explorer, or only in your own code? If only in your code, it might be that you're using Application permissions rather than Delegated...the "me" endpoints only work with Delegated, as they require a "user" context, so to speak (i.e. what is "me" for an application)

Comment: Inside Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using personal ms account instead of admin account from azure portal.